# Minimize $f(a,b,c) = \dfrac{1}{a²+b²+c²} +\dfrac{1}{9abc}$ subject to $a+b+c=1$ and $a,b,c>0$

Tags: inequality, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Minimize $f(a,b,c) = \dfrac{1}{a²+b²+c²} +\dfrac{1}{9abc}$ subject to
> $a+b+c=1$ and $a,b,c>0$

**My attempt:**

Since $f(a,b,c) \ge 0$, then we can minimizing the addends individually. Furthermore, minimizing fractions is the same as maximizing their denominators.

Apply the Lagrange Multiplier on ${a²+b²+c²}$ with the contraints $\implies a=b=c=\frac{1}{3}.$

Similarly, apply the Lagrange Multiplier on ${9abc}$ with the contraints $\implies a=b=c=\frac{1}{3}.$

Therefore, the minimum of $f\!\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right)=6.$

I'm looking for a better solution not using the Lagrange Multiplier.

Comment: This kind of inequality uses nontraditional method such as: EV, Schur, Muirhead inequality somehow. They belong to a class of inequalities that must be solved using other methods in addition to the AM-GM standard ones.

Comment: Replace $c$ with $1-a-b$.  Take the derivative of the resulting function with respect to $a$ and $b$, set those to zero, and solve for $a$ and $b$.  Only keep the solutions that satisfy the constraints.

Comment: It is very much false that you can minimize an expression by minimizing the addends individually.  For example, $(x-1)^2$ and $(x+1)^2$ both have minimums of $0$, but $(x-1)^2+(x+1)^2$ has a minimum of 2.  In this particular case, it was a coincidence that both expressions were minimized at the same point, but without that condition there isn't as nice a relationship between the minimum of the terms and the minimum of the expression.

Comment: @Aaron you're correct. I'm just lucky then. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: @Aaron It does not appear to be the case that $\frac{1}{a²+b²+c²}$ is minimized at $a = b = c = 1/3$.  For example, when $1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1 > 1/3 = (1/3)^2 + (1/3)^2 + (1/3)^2$.

Comment: When I first saw this problem, I thought applying Lagrange to both terms was the way to go, but it turns out the first term is maximized when $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this with AM-GMs. First note that as $(x+y+z)^2\geqslant 3(xy+yz+zx)$,
$$(ab+bc+ca)^2 \geqslant 3abc(a+b+c)=3abc $$
$\begin{align*}
 \implies 9abc(a^2+b^2+c^2) & \leqslant 3(a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+bc+ca)^2 \\
 &\leqslant 3\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)}3 \right)^3 \\
&=\frac19(a+b+c)^6=\frac19
\end{align*}$

Hence
$$f \geqslant \frac2{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(9abc)}}\geqslant \frac2{1/3}=6$$
with equality iff $a=b=c=\frac13$.

Answer (score 2):

This solution was posted by Arkady Alt on LinkedIn. Let $t:=ab+bc+ca.$ Since $3abc=3abc(a+b+c)\leq(ab+bc+ca)^2=t^2$,
$a^2+b^2+c^2=1-2t$ and $3t\leq(a+b+c)^2=1$ then
$$(1/(a^2+b^2+c^2))+(1/(9abc))-6≥(1/(1-2t))+(1/(3t^2))-6=$$
$$((4t+1)(1-3t)^2)/(3t^2(1-2t))≥0.$$